# Official way to create iOS icons?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, xamarin.ios, ipod-touch

I find it hard to believe that every developer creates their icons manually in various different ways but if that is the case, that is fine. I was wonder what the standard was for creating iOS icons (home screen icons, etc.)

Comment: Not really a programming question, is it...

Comment: @Oded, no, it isn't. Can't see anything programing related here.

Comment: I'm dragging up an old one, but actually think this is relevant. Programming questions aren't limited purely to typing syntax. As more and more engineers become "full stack" developers, questions such as this seem to be relevant. This is a resource we use to create ours: http://appicontemplate.com/

Comment: I agree with @MichaelShimmins.  I've read the "scope defined by the community" and it states questions regarding "software tools commonly used by programmers" as acceptable.  The problem may be that the question is subjective or too open-ended.  But last I checked, apps were made via programming, not wood and glue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apple do have some guidelines for creating icon of app. Via:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Doing some search, you'll find a lot of article talking about icon making experience. Such as:

http://eddit.com/notebook/archive/iphone_app_icon_template/

http://pixelresort.com/blog/iphone-app-icon-design-best-practises/

And here's a tutorial on making icon:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-design-tutorials/iphone-icon-design-creating-a-logo-for-bankapp/

I hope those links help.

Answer (score 5):

This could help you.. http://blog.cocoia.com/2010/iphone-ipad-icon-psd-template/

First hit for "iphone icon template" via Google. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by official way?

Application icons have standard sizes and format...
Format is png 24 bit.
Sizes vary depending on the use of the icon...